# PhpStorm protocol handler to open files directly from a URL unable to open file on mac

Tags: phpstorm

I not able to open files using phpstorm:// protocol

Example Url:

```
phpstorm://open?url=/var/www/html/testing/controllers/SiteController.php&line=126
```

I have followed the instructions on this link https://github.com/aik099/PhpStormProtocol

The urls are able to open the PhpStorm but not able to open the particular file.

I have gone through following links

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65879

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug

https://tracy.nette.org/en/open-files-in-ide

System environment

PhpStorm 2020.3.1
Build #PS-203.6682.180, built on December 30, 2020

Runtime version: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.63 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.16
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep

macOS Big Sur,
version 11.1

Php framework Yii2

Any help on how to debug this issue will be very thankful.

Comment: The "idea" or "phpstorm" protocols aren't supported by IDE yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65879. You should submit the issue you're experience to an app author: https://github.com/aik099/PhpStormProtocol/issues

Comment: Link formated in this format works.  <a href="http://localhost:63342/api/file?file={file}&line={line}" onclick="var a=new XMLHttpRequest;a.open(\'GET\',this.href);a.send(null);return!1">{text}</a>. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug/issues/172